# Pass & Display Javascript Variable in HTML Form Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I am trying to pass a Javascript variable to an HTML textbox and want that variable to be visible before passing to an onclick function.

First I encode a php variable (passed from another script) to a javascript variable:

```
var id = <?php echo json_encode($id);?>
```

I then try to attempt to make the value of the textbox equal to the javascript id variable:

```
<input type="text" id="getfromweb" value="">
<input type="button" value="Get From Web..." onclick="getFromWeb(document.getElementById('getfromweb').value = id)"><br>
```

However I am not seeing the id var displaying as the value of the textbox?

I thought the solution was to pass the id as the value in the function:

```
onclick="getFromWeb(document.getElementById('getfromweb').value = id)
```

But this doesn't work, that is the variable does not appear in the text box.

The getfromweb function starts off like this:

```
function getFromWeb(webid)
    {
        var webid=document.getElementById('getfromweb').value;
        var http_request=false;
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http_request.open('GET', 'getfromweb.php?id='+webid, false);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why this is, but playing with it, I find that using the variable name "id" is not working for me, but using "my_id" is. It shouldn't be a reserved word, but it seems to be treated differently in my version of Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your time in looking into this.  Unfortunately I need to pass the var id to the function because it passes this into a Mysql query :(

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Is it just not displaying, or is there an error being thrown in the console? May we also see the code for getFromWeb()?

Comment: I've updated my question to include a snippet of the get from web function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a bunch of weird stuff going on here.

1. The `webid` parameter in `getFromWeb(webid)` is lost when you overwrite it by declaring another variable with the same name: `var webid=document.getElementById('getfromweb').value;`
2. `onclick="getFromWeb(document.getElementById('getfromweb').value = id)"` this code only gets called when you click the button. That's what `onclick` means. `document.getElementById('getfromweb').value = id` is not running until you click it, even though you said you want it displayed before you click it. It won't do anything on page load until its clicked.

But why not use php to echo it in the html value in the first place? Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="getfromweb" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
```

Then you could simplify this:

```
 <input type="button" value="Get From Web..." onclick="getFromWeb();" />
```

And get rid of the parameter in this:

```
function getFromWeb()
{
    var webid=document.getElementById('getfromweb').value;
    ...
 }
```

Comment: This makes so much more sense to me!  Defo echoing the php variable in the value instead of encoding to a JavaScript var id is a lot simpler.  Thanks for such a thorough answer and vote from me :)